# How to Hook DirectX11 get Shader's bytecode

Tags: directx, shader, bytecode

【DirectX9 Get shader bytecode-】
I hook DrawIndexedPrimitive

```
HookCode(PPointer(g_DeviceBaseAddr + $148)^,@NewDrawIndexedPrimitive, @OldDrawIndexedPrimitive);    

function NewDrawIndexedPrimitive(const Device:IDirect3DDevice9;_Type: TD3DPrimitiveType; BaseVertexIndex: Integer; MinVertexIndex, NumVertices, startIndex, primCount: LongWord): HResult; stdcall;
var
    ppShader: IDirect3DVertexShader9;
    _Code:Pointer;
    _CodeLen:Cardinal;
begin
    Device.GetVertexShader(ppShader);//<------1.Get ShaderObject(ppShader)
    ppShader.GetFunction(nil,_CodeLen);
    GetMem(_Code,_CodeLen);
    ppShader.GetFunction(_Code,_CodeLen);//<----2.Get bytecode from ShaderObject(ppShader)
    Result:=OldDrawIndexedPrimitive(Self,_Type,BaseVertexIndex,MinVertexIndex, NumVertices, startIndex, primCount);
end;
```

【How to DirectX11 Get VSShader bytecode?】
I hook DrawIndexed

```
pDrawIndexed:=PPointer(PUINT_PTR(UINT_PTR(g_ImmContext)+0)^ + 12 * SizeOf(Pointer))^;
HookCode(pDrawIndexed,@NewDrawIndexed,@OldDrawIndexed);

procedure NewDrawIndexed(g_Real_ImmContext:ID3D11DeviceContext;IndexCount:     UINT;StartIndexLocation: UINT;BaseVertexLocation: Integer); stdcall;
var
    game_pVertexShader: ID3D11VertexShader;
        ppClassInstances: ID3D11ClassInstance;
        NumClassInstances: UINT
begin
    g_Real_ImmContext.VSGetShader(game_pVertexShader,ppClassInstances,NumClassInstances);    //<------1.Get ShaderObject(game_pVertexShader)
    .....//<----【2.Here's how to get bytecode from ShaderObject(game_pVertexShader)?】
    OldDrawIndexed(ImmContext, IndexCount, StartIndexLocation, BaseVertexLocation);
end;
```

Another way:

HOOK CreateVertexShader()

but

HOOK need to be created before the game CreateVertexShader, HOOK will not get bytecode if the game is running later,I need to get bytecode at any time like DirectX9

Comment: Can you clarify your question?

Comment: What is the DirectX11 version of IDirect3DVertexShader9 :: GetFunction

Comment: Please put all relevant information into your question, not to the comment section